# Android simulator is not loading react-native application

Tags: android, android-studio, npm, android-virtual-device

After the npm start, when the android simulator is open and running with Pixel3, if I 'click' a (for Android emulator), this error appears and the app does not open on the emulator

```
Trying to open the project on Android...
Installing Expo on device
/Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Failed to install C:\Users\35192\.expo\android-apk-
cache\Exponent-2.16.1.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed to parse
/data/app/vmdl1083085082.tmp/base.apk: Failed to load asset path /data/app/vmdl1083085082.tmp/base.apk]
```

Comment: Try running simulator first and then deploy expo android app. Also try uninstalling expo project and run again. If still it doesnt work, you can try creating a standalone app and install the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. **Please Install the Required SDKs as shown in this figure**

From Android Studio, select `File` then `Settings...` Under the `Appearance & Behavior` category, then under the `System Settings` category, select the `HTTP Proxy` page. Select `Manual proxy configuration` and adjust accordingly.

From Android Studio, select `File`, then `Settings`... Under the `Appearance & Behavior` category, then under the `System Settings` category, select the `Android SDK` page.

Select the `SDK Platforms` tab, if it’s not selected by default. Select the `Show Package Details` checkbox. Under `Android API 28`, check the boxes for `Intel x86 Atom System Image` and `Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image`

[image]
[image]

2. **Configure Environment**

Click `Environment variables` . Under `System variables`, click `New...` Enter `ANDROID_SDK` as the variable name and `%LOCALAPPDATA\Android\Sdk` as the variable value. Under System variables, edit Path. If your configuration takes a single string, append `;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` (preceding semicolon). If your configuration takes multiple strings, append `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` (no preceding semicolon). Click OK, then click OK again.

Hope to help you

Comment: I have an AMD processor, so I'm unable to install the 'intel x86 Emulator ...'